# Kendo grid inside splitter next page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui, splitter

Here's my layout.  I'm using a Kendo splitter control.  The left pane contains a menu and the right is the main content.  Some of the content pages contain kendo grids that can contain several pages of data.  My problem is that when the user clicks on the next page of the grid, it performs a post back and the whole page refreshes taking the user back to the home page.  The left menu loads the right panel using javascript.  Does anyone know how to get around this?

In another words, I need the grid to load the next page and target the right side of the splitter control.  How do I "Ajaxify" the next page of the grid control?

Comment: Are you using kendo ui mvc  extensions ?

Comment: yes.  I changed my code to use Ajax, but now I'm getting a circular reference error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your Grid is configured for [Server Binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/server-binding) - if so you need to change it to [Ajax binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding) and there is not other way to put it inside a Splitter which content is loaded with Ajax.

Comment: I had a problem with circular reference after I changed it to Ajax.  It turned out that all I had to do was to change the model reference on top of the page to inside the grid definition.  For example, instead of having @model IEnumerable<App.Models.UserGroup> on top of the page I added to the grid:  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<App.Models.UserGroup>().  I guess the circular reference occurred because it's trying to serialize the whole object on page load.  Anyway, that was really a different issue than my original question.  Thank you so much for your answer.